# How do I have more than 6 tabs open in Chrome without the 6th tab blocking the Minimize button?

Tags: google-chrome

Every time I have 6 or more tabs open in Chrome the 3 right-top corner buttons start getting covered by the tabs and prevent me from using the minimize button etcetera.  How do I fix it?

I'm on Win 7 Pro with the latest version of Chrome.

Comment: I'll guess that you do not have a `Use System Title Bar and Borders` menu option. Right?

Comment: @zero2cx: I don't see it unless I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: That is not normal; the tabs should minimize *to the left* of the control buttons. If it happened once or twice, that would be one thing, but if like you said, it happens *every* time, then it’s a bug. Update Chrome and see if it goes away.

Comment: What version of Chrome are you using? In the future, it is helpful to know what version you have of things. Thanks.

Comment: My Chrome IS updated to the latest available.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux (and maybe others):

1. Right-click in the *background* of the tab area (click near the `New tab` plus-sign icon).
2. Enable `Use System Title Bar and Borders`

This checkbox can also be found in Chrome `Appearance` configuration (click the wrench, select settings).

Comment: Which background area?  I right-clicked but I see no "System.." option!

Comment: @verve Okay. The question as originally posted didn't specify an OS, so I took a shot. Still, maybe my answer can help the unix-like users here.